# External tables: Why create statistics?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, polybase

The documentation for Polybase says that creating statistics for External Tables will help getting better execution plans. This question is about when the External Data Source is another SQL Server.

I guess the better execution plan is on the External Data Source, i.e. for pushdown computations (for where clauses, joins and aggregates).

To get a good execution plan the optimizer also has to know what indexes are on the table. Can the optimizer use the statistics on the remote server (the External Data Source)?

If yes, what are the benefits of creating the statistics locally on the External Table? If the optimizer has too look at the indexes on the remote server, then it might as well look at the statistics...

Please provide references in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

For External Tables, where the external data source is another SQL Server instance, the instance with the External Tables (the local instance) cannot reuse the statistics from the external data source. If we get pushdown computation, then the query that will be sent to the external data source will get compiled "over there", because the local instance does not know e.g. what indexes exist on the actual table. The statistics for the external table is not to help with pushdown computation, but the rest of the execution plan, i.e. after the "remote query" operator.

E.g. there might be joins with local tables or a sort operator with the result of the "remote query" operator. So the statistics will help in getting better estimates of rows returned by the "remote query" operator and this will help with the rest of the execution plan.

If all the work in the query happens in the "remote query" operator then it seems having local statistics will not help. The remote query can use the statistics on the actual table.

Should one create statistics on the external table? It depends on the query.

My reference is troubleshooting queries with external tables